# Normalize path expressions for virtual file system

Tags: c#, path, relative-path

Say you have for instance a [`ZipArchive`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Using this class, one handles a file system that is not attached to the real file system.

Say the archive has the following structure:

```
.
├── Foo
│   └── File1
└── Bar
    └── File2
```

Now one can read `File1`. If `File1` contains a relative reference to `File2`, it is written as `../Bar/File2`.

The question is how one can combine the directory of `File1` (`Foo/`) with the path `../Bar/File2` such that the result is `Bar/File2` (the `ZipArchive` can't handle combinations of relative with absolute paths).

Tried solutions with (`dir` and `rel`):

- [`Path.Combine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`(dir,rel)` only places a `/` between the two, thus the entry can't be resolved;
- `new`[`DirectoryInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.fullname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`(Path.Combine(dir,rel)).FullName` generates a part with the current directory (`cd`) included; and
- [`Path.GetFullPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfullpath%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)`(Path.Combine(dir,rel)).FullName` does the same

How can one normalize such relative paths? One can of course write a normalizer oneself, but the odds are high the algorithm will lack some parts of the specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: simply add `/` in the front of the first path, such that `Path.GetFullPath` thinks the first file originates from the root.

```
string fullpath = Path.GetFullPath ((Path.Combine ("/",dir,rel))).Substring (1);
```

One also needs to perform `.Substring` to eliminate that slash later in the process. This is however not a sustainable solution since it makes the assumption one uses a *Linux* file system and the elimiation of the slash isn't safe either.